# Error : ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

This is the parent component. Added a child component and passed the form. Here Using both the form Control Name & NgModel(Is this a best practice). While loading the page console error  " ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive."

```
<div class="inner-wrapper">   
    <form [formGroup]="form">
     <pat-demo-information [group]="form"></pat-demo-information>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="ui-input-group">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="notif.en.No" formControlName="epiNo">
                    <span class="input-bar"></span>
                            <label>No.</label>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>  
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'patient-demographic-information',
  templateUrl: './pat-demo-information'
})
export class PatDemoInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() patientForm: FormGroup
    noti: MaltreatmentNoti;


  instid: number;
  instPatientid: number;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;

  enMpi: Mpi = new Mpi();

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notification = new MaltreatmentNoti();
    this.notification.enMpi = new Mpi();
    yhis.getFromGroup();
  }


  private getFromGroup() {
    this.patientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'instPatientid': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),

    })
  }
}
```

//child html

```
<div class="panel panel-default" [formGroup]="patientForm">
    <div class="panel-heading">Patient Information</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="ui-input-group">
                    <ng-select #reportInstitute [items]="selectInst" id="reportingInstitute"
                               [virtualScroll]="true" placeholder="Select" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value"
                               [(ngModel)]="instid" formControlName="patientInstId" required> 
                    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">{{item.label}}</ng-template>
                    </ng-select>
                    <span class="input-bar"></span>
                    <label>Institution<span class="mdtr">*</span></label>
                <span *ngIf="patientForm.controls['patientInstId'].hasError('required') && (isError || patientForm.controls['patientInstId'].touched)" class="tooltiptext">{{'Institution is required'}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here using reactive forms for validation & for other wise  use template driven, to get & set values.

while loading the page, an error in console.

```
RROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

      Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

      Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
       <input formControlName="firstName">
       <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </div>
```

What would be the reason for this error ? what is the solution ?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: user630209, if you want give value to a formControl, make it using setValue or when you create the FormControl. The use of [(ngModel)]="variable" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" in a ReactiveForm it used for manage a variable that NOT belong to the formGroup. e.g. you want a check, so if it is checked, show more controls in the form, BUT you don't want this variable belong to the formGroup. then use [(ngModel)] with [ngModelOptions]

Answer (score 7):

> Using both the form Control Name & NgModel(Is this a best practice)

No, It's not a good practice.

If we use **[`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)** then don't use  **`[(ngModel)]`**.

Still if you want to use the both then as stated in the error itself, use `ngModelOptions`

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Answer (score 2):

For using `ngModel` you have to use template driven forms for which you should import `FormsModule` to your `ngModule`. Here you are using `ReactiveFormsModule` Which should use `FormGroup` that create `formControls`.

Here you need not to give `formControlName`. Instead you give only `ngModel` with standalone option

**For template driven form you should use ngModel**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="notif.en.No" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

In child

```
<ng-select #reportInstitute [items]="selectInst" 
id="reportingInstitute" [virtualScroll]="true" 
placeholder="Select" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value"
[(ngModel)]="instid" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true} required>
```

**For reactive form you should use fromControlName**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control"formControlName="epiNo">
```

In child

```
<ng-select #reportInstitute [items]="selectInst" 
id="reportingInstitute" [virtualScroll]="true" 
placeholder="Select" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value"
formControlName="patientInstId" required>
```

The idea is you should use either ngModel or formControlName.

Answer (score 1):

In some reason we have to mix ngModel and formControlName. We have used ngModel for data and formControl for validation.

**But this is not a good approach.**

I recommend you to **choose one from Reactive & Template Driven form** and use for your entire application.

Refer: https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 0):

Dont use [(ngModel)] with formcontrol as its not the best practice .

Alternatively :-

you can try [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

This will indicate the form as standalone but please avoid doing this things .